# Django recursive relationship: How to remove object from Manager object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a following class(other fields are trivial(author, etc), so omitted).

```
class Article(models.Model):

origin = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_revision")
```

I want to store all revisions of an article, in `a.website_article_revision` list. When after I `add` a revision to that list, like that `a.website_article_revision.add(rev)` it automatically gets added to the `Article.objects` manager and this can be understood since the revision object itself is an article instance. But I don't want any revision to appear in the manager object, only in a list attribute of an article object `a.website_article_revision`.

P.S. I really don't want to create subclass.

Comment: Can you rephrase the last sentence?

Comment: @v1k45, if what I want is impossible, then I have to subclass that Article model, for revisions. I just wanted to write elegant and small code if ever possible.

Comment: Sorry I confused you, I was asking about this line _But I don't want any revision to appear in the manager object...._

Comment: @v1k45 Whenever I add a revision to an article objects `website_article_revision` list, it also appears in `Article.objects.all()`  I want to use objects in this manager for articles only(not revision article instances, only original articles).
Revision objects have the same fields as original article, since they both made of a single Article class.

Comment: You can add a field like `is_latest_version` to `Article` and assign its value as `True` __only__ for the original article and then use `.filter()` to return only original articles.

Comment: @v1k45, yeah, I was thinking of this, but then I'll have to filter every time when i want to get articles, wich is ugly :)

Comment: The problem is I have 3 different type of post and only one of them is article. A have abstract parent class for them and actually `origin` field is defined there :)

Comment: You can override the default queryset by using a custom manager then you won't have to filter every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset):

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ArticleManager, self).get_queryset().filter(origin=None)

class Article(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleManager()
    origin = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_revision")
```

This will replace the default `objects` manager in your `Article` model, and `Article.objects.all()` will return all articles who's `origin` is `null`.

I'm assuming that checking if `origin is None` is how you want to determine if any given article object is NOT a revision.

EDIT: You might want to change the origin `ForeignKey` to a `OneToOneField`. After all, an Article may have only one revision, and that revision may have another revision, and so on.

Comment: Sounds like a solution for me. I only afraid filtering will consume too much server resources and maybe i should write a couple of dozen lines of code. What is more important length or perfomance?(assuming a hypothetical website with 100K articles).

Comment: @koala-lava Honestly, I'd try this solution before subclassing your Article model. With this solution, you have a nice "chain" of articles, each one pointing to it's successor. If you subclass, you'll have to keep the first version of the article in the Article table, and put the revisions in their own separate table, and you'll have to sort that table by date to find the last one. Also, Django will do at least 1 join in order to figure out if an article has revisions or not. With this solution, no joins are needed because you just check if the foreign key is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to model your revisions yourself, there is [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) which does the job for you:

> **django-reversion** is an extension to the Django web framework that provides comprehensive version control facilities.

It is properly documented.